# Golang: remove structs older than 1h from slice

Tags: go

So I'm building a small utility that listens on a socket and stores incoming messages as a structs in a slice:

```
var points []Point

type Point struct {
    time   time.Time
    x    float64
    y    float64
}

func main() {
    received = make([]Point, 0)
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":8900")
    // (...)
}


func processIncomingData(data string) {

    // Parse icoming data that comes as: xValue,yValue
    inData = strings.Split(data, ",")
    x, err := strconv.ParseFloat(inData[0], 64);
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    y, err := strconv.ParseFloat(inData[1], 64);
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Store the new Point
    points = append(points, Point{
        time:   time.Now(),
        x:    x,
        y:    y,
    })

    // Remove points older than 1h ?

}
```

Now, as you might imagine this will quickly fill my RAM. **What's the best way (faster execution) to remove points older than 1h** after appening each new one? I'll be getting new points 10-15 times peer second.

Thank you.

Comment: Since they're in order, what's wrong with the obvious method of slicing off the oldest values from the start of the slice?

Comment: @JimB: ah, but with reslicing, doesn't it (new slice) keep referencing the same big array? I'll happily be proven wrong :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: It's not a problem when you're continually appending, since the head of the slice is wasted only until a new array is allocated. You would use up the already allocated memory, which is no loss since you've already allocated it, then the old array is dropped completely when you need to extend the slice.

Comment: @JimB: I see, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach I've used several times is to start a goroutine early in the project that looks something like this:

```
go cleanup()

...

func cleanup() {
  for {
    time.Sleep(...)
    // do cleanup
  }
}
```

Then what you could do is iterate over `points` using `time.Since(point.time)` to figure out how old each piece of data is. If it's too old, there's a [slice trick](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) to remove an item from a slice given it's position:

```
points = append(points[:i], points[i+1:]...)
```

(where `i` is the index to remove)

Because the points are in the slice in order of the time they were added, you could speed things up by simply finding the first index that isn't an hour old and doing `points = points[i:]` to chop off the old points from the beginning of the slice.

You may run into problems if you get a request that accesses the array while you're cleaning it up. Adding a `sync.Mutex` can help with that. Just lock the mutex before the cleanup and also attempt to lock the mutex anywhere else you write to the array. This may be premature optimization though. I'd experiment without the mutex before adding it in as this would effectively make interacting with `points` a serial operation and slow the service down.

The `time.Sleep(...)` in the loop is to prevent from cleaning too often. You might be tempted to set it to an hour since you want to delete points older than that but you might end up with a situation where a point is added immediately after a cleanup. On the next cleanup it'll be 59 mins old and you don't delete it, on the NEXT cleanup it's nearly 2 hours old. My rule of thumb is that I attempt to clean up every 1/10 the amount of time I want to allow an object to stay in memory but that's rather arbitrary. This approach means an object could be at most 1h 5m 59s old when it's deleted.

Comment: @JimB, it's ok. A lot of the hacks around slices are more cumbersome then they ought to be. Definitely something to keep an eye on.

Comment: On the contrary, I prefer how go doesn't hide the slice internals, so you can see precisely what's going on. Make it really obvious when code implements "delete" as O(1) or O(n).

Comment: Thats an interesting approach doing the cleanup not when I get new data but periodically. Thank you.

Comment: When taking this approach for long running processes, it is very important to be sure that your cleanup function never terminates. If it might panic, be sure to add a `recover()` that starts up the cleanup again. Your sample seems like it's a lightweight operation so that's probably not that necessary.